# Prevent previously retrived related entity from update in Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am developing an ASP.NET mvc project using Entity Framework code first approach. But I am having a problem of related data is updated when I insert new data to database.

I have entities similar like this

```
User{
   public int Id{ get;set; }
   public string Name{ get;set; }
   public string Country { get;set; }
}

Account{
   public int Id{ get;set; }
   public decimal Balance { get;set; }
   public int UserId { get;set }

   public virtual User User;
}
```

I have this methods in repository

```
public User User(int id)
{
    return context.Users.Find(id);
}

public Account CreateAccount(User user,decimal balance)
{
   Account ac = new Account{
      Balance = 5000,
      UserId = user.id
   };
   context.Accounts.Add(ac);
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I am doing something like this in controller action

```
   public ActionResult Post(ViewModel model)
   {
       User user = repo.User(model.UserId);
       //Do a lot of stuffs with user object
       //Eg I changed country
       user.Country = "Just a temporary country. This should not be changed in database";
       . 
       .
       //Then create an account
       repo.CreateAccount(user,model.Balance);
       return View();
   }
```

As you can see above I changed country before I create account. But when I create account, country value in database also changed. This is just a simple example to my problem.

Is it possible to stop Entity framework from updating previous retrieved related entity when I created another related entity? In my example, I stop country name updated when I create account for user. Is this possible, and if so, how can I get it?

Comment: Somewhere you have to mark the user as unchanged, but with all these repository layers I have no idea where you should do that. It's not clear if all repositories use the same `context` instance (it looks like it, which is good), I don't understand why a repo calls `SaveChanges`; that's very inconvenient. Also, why do you do "a lot of stuff" while it isn't saved?

Comment: I am doing SaveChanges in repository cause I am using Ninject for dependency injection.

Comment: How to mark user as unchanged? eg - context.Users.Unchanged(). I do not see any method for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detach user entity before call CreateAccount method or in, like this:

```
context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

or in repo User method use from AsNoTracking, like this

```
public User User(int id)
{
    return context.Users.Where(e=>e.Id == id)
        .AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(id);
}
```

and at any time want to update user use explicitly method for updating:

```
context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
```